# ProxyAddresses - filter on Get-ADUser not working with variable

Tags: powershell, get-aduser

I want to find users having in ProxyAddresses a specyfic mail address.
I would like to make this two lines working

```
$mail = "person@domain.com"
Get-ADUser -Filter {proxyaddresses -like "*$mail*"}  - not working
```

like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {proxyaddresses -like "*person@domain.com*"}
```

I have tried those but it fails:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {proxyaddresses -like "*$($mail)*"}
Get-ADUser -Filter {proxyaddresses -match "$mail"}
```

I would like to have this command working with a variable ($mail = "person@domain.com")

Comment: The filter is actually supposed to be a string. Change it to this `Get-AdUser -Filter "proxyaddresses -like '*$mail*'"`